# Update column choices in sharepoint based on another list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I was trying to update the choices available to be selected in a sharepoint list based on a value in a different list. For instance, I have the values 1,2,3,4 in list 1. If I add a row to list 1, there are now 1,2,3,4,5 in a certain column. I want to update the choices to be updated in the first list.

Comment: So you are talking about _lookup columns_. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with moe, that sounds alot like you are talking about lookup columns, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632

Answer (score 1):

I agree with moe and Kasper, you can create lookup column to achieve your requirement. 
Eg: you have column1 in list1, column1 contain values (1,2,3,4,5).

You can create lookup column in list2 which get information from list1 and in column1 column:

[image]